# Yii code listing widget

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, yii

I was wondering if the Yii framework already has a widget for pretty-printing source code on a web page. I mean with line numbers, alignment and perhaps some nice keyword coloring.
Thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [CTextHighlighter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTextHighlighter).  The Yii playground has a good example demo of this working complete with source code [here](http://www.yiiplayground.cubedwater.com/index.php?r=UiModule/ui_other/textHighlighter).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CMarkdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMarkdown) widget to pretty-print code. CMarkdown offers a lot of options to make blocks of text look good.

You can enable syntax highlight code with CMarkdown by placing your code in a block like this:

```
~~~
[code showLineNumbers=1]
Enter code here.
~~~
```

showLineNumbers=1 is optional and enables line numbering for the block.

`code` should be one of ABAP, CPP, CSS, DIFF, DTD, HTML, JAVA, JAVASCRIPT, MYSQL, PERL, PHP, PYTHON, RUBY, SQL or XML.

Example:

```
~~~
[php showLineNumbers=1]
<?php
    echo phpinfo();
?>
~~~
```

You can use CMarkdown in a view like this:

```
$this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true'));
    echo $content;
$this->endWidget();
```